# Wrapper function for read() doesn't compile

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm trying to write a wrapper function for read() , under Linux .

Please go easy on me , since this is my first time using Wrappers :)

Given the code the `my_wrappers.c` file :

```
#include "my_wrappers.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

ssize_t my_read (int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
  long ret;
  extern int errno;

  __asm__ __volatile__ ("pushl %%ebx\n\t"
                        "movl %%esi,%%ebx\n\t"
                        "int $0x80\n\t"
                        "popl %%ebx"
                      : "=a" (ret)
                      : "0" (SYS_read), "S" ((long) fd),
                        "c" ((long) buf) "d" ((long) count): "bx");
  if (ret >= 0)
  {
    return (int) ret;
  }
  errno = -ret;
  return -1;
}
```

and `my_wrappers.h` file :

```
#ifndef __MY_WRAPPERS_H_
#define __MY_WRAPPERS_H_

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int my_open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
ssize_t my_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
int my_close(int fd);

pid_t my_fork(void);

#endif
```

I'm only allowed to use call the `libc` wrappers, i.e. , I'm not allowed to call open(), read() and etc.

What's wrong with this code ? maybe because I didn't use the number of the system call table ?

The error from Eclipse : - `‘SYS_read’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Regards

Ron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#include <syscall.h>` or possibly `#include <sys/syscall.h>`

Comment: Is it a must ? The lecturer said that only : #include <unistd.h> & #include <sys/types.h>

Comment: Without it the compiler can't see the declaration of `SYS_read()`.  Your other option is to provide an `extern` declaration for it. In practice, you're better off including the header file but if your instructor insists, you can use the `extern`.

Comment: I didn't get you , you mean to add "extern" before "0" (SYS_read) ?

Comment: No, I mean you could provide an extern declaration for `SYS_read()` at some point before you attempt to use that symbol.  If you're unfamiliar with it, you might want to read up on it.  You should know that while an extern function declaration is perfectly legal but generally considered bad style.  The preferred mechanism is to include the relevant header file.